# Wrong app icon on push notification badge iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, push-notification, badge

I have implemented push notifications for my iPhone application. Everything is working fine. Only problem is when I receive notification during app is in background the iOS notification shows wrong icon for the notification. Like if notification came for App A it shows the icon of App B in notification badge.

What can cause this? Is it certificates problem or what? Any idea?

Comment: Check the icons you app, the notification center uses one of the smaller icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have some images name like "icon.png", that will be displayed in push notification

Answer (score 0):

Few more thing can cause this issue,

If you have used same push profile for two different project. Than also this will happen.

Moreover if you have specified Small-Icon.png in you .plist file than that would be used as a push notification icon in notification screen.

Please make sure this things in your projects.